# sessionWithConfiguration: delegate: delegateQueue: working in simulator but not in device

Tags: background-service, nsurlsessionconfiguration

I am downloading multiple audio files using background transfer service, everything was working as expected till yesterday. Now when I run the project it stuck on the second line of following lines -

NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:@"com.example.myapp"];

session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];  //Did not return anything

I have downloaded multiple demo apps but they also stuck on the same line, although they are working as expected in simulator as well as for "defaultSessionConfiguration" in device.

What could be the problem then?

Thanks for any help